# Free GeoSserver SLD for 2009 TIGER line data (preferably Google Maps color scheme)

Tags: geoserver, sld

I need to render a base map using OpenLayers. I have downloaded 2009 TIGER line data. I need to get up and running quickly. I think I can save some time if I use ready made SLDs, instead of designing them my elf.

I am looking for some decent looking SLDs especially for the road network and its labels. In fact I prefer if the SLDs are Google Maps style color scheme!

Please point me to links where I can download these SLDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was sure that there used to be a google like SLD but I can't find it - you may be able to start with https://github.com/mitchelljj/openstreetmap-sld and convert it to give what you are looking for.

Alternatively [AtlasStyler](http://en.geopublishing.org/AtlasStyler) and [UDig](http://udig.refractions.net/) both provide graphical style editors which will allow you to build a style that matches Google as closely as you need.

Finally you may find my discussion on styling OSM data (http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/data/openstreetmap/index.html) useful - you can see the results at http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver/www/pa/pa3.html